# Using Metadata in triggers to remove hard coded keywords

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-metadata

I have custom metadata type with api name program_mdt in which I have created two fields called Email_Keyword__c and Body__c. In the below trigger I am trying to get rid of hard coded values in the   if(filename.contains('report')) and the defining body of the email in step4.

I am not sure how to proceed from here to replace hard coded values with custom metadata. In this case i am trying to send out an email when file name contains the values that exist in Email_Keyword__c  field of program__mdt.

```
    trigger FilesAccountUpload_Tr on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) {
  set<Id>setAccIds = new set<Id>();
    set<Id>setCntDocIds = new set<Id>();
    List<Program__mdt> lstMetaData = [SELECT Email_c FROM Program__mdt];

    Map<Id, String> filestitlemaps  = new Map<Id, String>();
    Map<Id, String> accnamemaps   = new Map<Id, String>();

    for(ContentDocument c : [select id, title from ContentDocument]){
  filestitlemaps.put(c.id,c.title);
  }

    for(Appointment__c app: [select id,Name from Appointment__c]){
    accnamemaps.put(app.id,app.name);
    }

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Set<String> KeywordSet = new Set<String>();  

    for(ContentDocumentLink clIterator : trigger.new) {
        string strObjPrefix = String.valueOf(clIterator.LinkedEntityId).substring(0, 3);
        if(strObjPrefix == Appointment__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()) {
          setCntDocIds.add(clIterator.ContentDocumentId);
            setAccIds.add(clIterator.LinkedEntityId);
              string filename =filestitlemaps.get(clIterator.ContentDocumentId); 
        string accountname = accnamemaps.get(clIterator.LinkedEntityId);
        Set<String> KeywordSet = new Set<String>();




            if(filename.contains('report')){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
      sendTo.add('test@gmail.com');
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
      mail.setReplyTo('test@gmail.com');
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('File gets uploaded');

            // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
      List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
      ccTo.add('test@gmail.com');
      mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);

            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
      mail.setSubject(accountname+'File uploaded');
      String body = 'Dear Team , '; 
      //body += +filename+'files was uploaded';
      body += +Program_Setting__mdt.Email_Body__c;

            mail.setHtmlBody(body);

      // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
      mails.add(mail);

            // Step 6: Send all emails in the master list
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
      }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply query the [Custom metadata types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_accessing.htm&type=5) like below:

```
program__mdt[] programs = [SELECT MasterLabel, QualifiedApiName, Email_Keyword__c, Body__c FROM Threat_Tier_Mapping__mdt];
```

Then, you use these values like below:

```
if(filename.contains(programs[0].Email_Keyword__c))
```

This is, if you are sure there will be only 1 record. However, you can add `WHERE` condition to get exactly the record metadata-type needed in query like below:

```
program__mdt[] programs = [SELECT MasterLabel, QualifiedApiName, Email_Keyword__c, Body__c FROM Threat_Tier_Mapping__mdt WHERE Email_Keyword__c='report'];
```

**ADDED BASED ON COMMENTS**

I would recommend you to use Email templates and use `setTemplateId`. The content can be dynamically generated through merge fields in template and depends on Account/Contact/other object.

For further info, You can check [How to send an Email Template via Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180980/how-to-send-an-email-template-via-apex)

Note: setting the body through custom metadata type and concatenating OR replacing dynamic data in apex class is not scalable and will become very complex to implement.

Comment: Thanks very much mate. It worked out for the Email_Keyword__c but I am still not sure about making email Body__c dynamic. I understand that we have queried body from the custom data but I am not how to place it in my step4 of the trigger. please suggest  // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
      mail.setSubject(accountname+'File uploaded');
      String body = 'Dear Team , '; 
      //body += +filename+'files was uploaded';
      body += +Program_Setting__mdt.Email_Body__c;

            mail.setHtmlBody(body);

Comment: I think this will become very complex. added in answer

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you already know how to create and populate a Custom Metadata type.

With that, your code can have a snippet like this one

```
Boolean containsKeyword = false;

for (Program__mdt prog : [Select Email_Keyword__c from Program__mdt]) {
  if (filename.contains(prog.Email_Keyword__c)) {
    containsKeyword = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (containsKeyword) {
   //Do your thing
}
```

That way, if at least one keyword is found, you'll execute your logic.

PS: I see that in your code you already have `lstMetaData`, you can (should) use that instead of the SoQL I added in my snippet if that list is pointing to the same Custom Metadata Type.

**Update from OP's comments**

Salesforce offers templates built-in in the platform. You can do them in [Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&type=5) or [Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_templates_lightning_parent.htm&type=5).

Templates are going to allow you to merge fields, set subjects and even change the text without having to write code (which is why, I assume, you tried to do it with Custom Metadata).

The main takeaway of using sending emails via Apex is that some limits will apply. (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000312442) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323568&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)).

I do not recommend you try your own merging via Custom Metadata. Re-inventing standard functionality is not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! I understand the keyword scenario however I am still confused how to call and define the body content in trigger from the metadata.

Comment: Hi there, you're really asking two very different things here. As @salesforce-sas outlined above, the second question is very different. I'll update my answer as well, but I agree with him in that you probably want a template and not a CMDT for it.