# How to Send email to multiple user from batch apex

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am trying to create a batch that will run every day and will find the contacts which match the criteria. at the moment the code I have written is sending email to the same email address (time the contact match criteria)

I want to send an email to that specifc user which the records belong not to same user agaian and again. Below is my code.

```
 global class RTS implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Email,RTS_Count__c FROM Contact WHERE RTS_Count__c = 1 and Email !=null';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global String body='';
    global List<Contact> ContactList = new List<Contact>();
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {
     for(Contact a : scope)
     {
         ContactList.add(a);
     }

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  

    for(Contact a:ContactList){
        String[] toadd=new String[]{a.Email};
        string b =  'hello' ; 
        body += b ;
        mail1.setToAddresses(toadd);
        mail1.setSubject('Test mail');
        mail1.setPlainTextBody('this is a test mail');
        mail1.setHtmlBody(body);
        lstEmail.add(mail1);
    }
    System.debug(body);
       Messaging.SendEmail(lstEmail);
}  

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. - use public, not global; also the for loop can iterate over `scope`; you don't need `ContactList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();` line to inside the `for(Contact a:ContactList)...` loop to create a new message instance to use every time.

Comment: Thanks, Moonpie it worked, also is there any way we can use the email template here?

Comment: @SantoshRana : I've not done that myself that I recall, but it looks as simple as - personalized for your specific code - `mail1.setTemplateId(someTemplateId)`. However, you will probably want to do some sort of check to ensure that the _someTemplateId_ is valid/for a valid template. | https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/180980/81648 | (pay special care if using merge fields)